# Configuring raw and analytics databases with dbt

Tags: dbt

I have been reading dbt's [How we configure Snowflake](https://blog.getdbt.com/how-we-configure-snowflake/) guide which explains the rationale behind having a `raw` database and an `analytics` database. Raw data is loaded into your warehouse into `raw` (e.g. by using Fivetran) and `analytics` is used by dbt to save transformed data/views for data analysts/scientists.

However, I can't seem to find any guides on how to actually set this up. The profiles.yml file needs to point to where the raw data is, so that dbt can begin transforming. However, this file also seems to dictate the database and schema into which transformed data/views are saved.

Where in dbt's many .yml files do I specify globally where to save transformed data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set up your `profiles.yml`, which does NOT live in the actual project but rather in the `~/.dbt` folder on your machine, such that it refers to your target database/schema. For development, this would look like what you see below. [For production on dbt Cloud](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/dbt-cloud/cloud-configuring-dbt-cloud/connecting-your-database). Now, you just set up your sources like usual (see third block below). There is no universal sources option, just a target database/schema.

[Profiles.yml Docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/profiles.yml) and [Snowflake Profile Docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/warehouse-profiles/snowflake-profile)

```
-- profiles.yml

my_profile:
  target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
      type: snowflake
      account: <snowflake_server>
      user: my_user
      password: my_password
      role: my_role
      database: analytics
      warehouse: dev_wh
      schema: dbt_<myname>
      threads: 1
      client_session_keep_alive: False
```

```
-- dbt_project.yml

name: 'my_dbt_models'
version: '1.0.0'
config-version: 2

profile: 'my_profile'
...
...
...
```

[Sources Docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/using-sources)

```
-- src.yml 

version: 2
sources:
  - name: jaffle_shop
    database: raw
    tables: 
      - name: orders
```

In the model:

`raw.jaffle_shop.orders` becomes `{{ source( 'jaffle_shop' , 'orders' ) }}`

Note, dbt processes this source such that it assumes the name is the schema by default, however, I've discovered that you can really name it whatever you want and add in a schema if you want to give it a special name.
For example…

```
sources:
  - name: my_special_name
    database: raw
    schema: jaffle_shop
    tables: 
      - name: orders
```

In the model:

`raw.jaffle_shop.orders` becomes `{{ source( 'my_special_name' , 'orders' ) }}`

I hope all that made sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Anna, it has helped me to better understand the roles of `profiles.yml` and the various model-related .yml files in ~/models. I made a further breakthrough when inspecting `dbt_project.yml` and realised that I could set where packages look for databases in `vars`.